# Check exit status of function with itself exit status

Tags: bash, exit-code

I have a function `ff` in `1.sh` with exit status `33`.
When I call this function in `2.sh` and call function `ff` and if the exit status is `33`, then my `2.sh` is broken.
How can I do a continue step?
like this:

```
if [ exit_of_ff -ne 0 ]
then
 continue
fi
```

Comment: I don't understand your specific question. Please be more precise, and make an effort to use well-constructed sentences to convey your problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what do you want to "continue" be more specific

Comment: @BertrandMartel I'm guessing he doesn't want his 2.sh to break, but rather catch the exit and continue working

Comment: BertrandMartel - you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but a formatted comment.

If you have

```
ff() {
    if [ some_condition ]; then
        return 33
    fi
    return
}
```

Then, normally to check the error condition, you would do

```
if ! ff; then
    echo function ff returned non-zero
    exit
fi
echo function ff returned success
```

If you want to store the return status

```
ff
status=$?
if [[ $status -eq 33 ]]; then ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue like this:

if ( ff $parameter )
then
   ff $parameter
fi

in ff I have 3 parameters which are not accessible after (  )